# Overlaying images

Tags: java, image-processing

[![Edit: I added a photo of the error am getting.][1]][1]I am still very much a beginner in programming, and i am facing an issue with a code that i am hoping someone could help me with. I found the java code below for overlaying and comparing the pixels of two images in an online forum. When i try to compile the code i get a syntax error. Hope you can help me find the error. Thanks in advance.

```
package stackexchange;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PictureOverlayTest {
    /*
     * Four variables, three for the wanted BufferedImages, one String for the
     * Path of the third Image, which does not already exist.
     */`

    private BufferedImage image1;
    private BufferedImage image2;
    private BufferedImage image3;

    private String pathImage3;

    public PictureOverlayTest(String filePathAndName1, String filePathAndName2,
            String filePathAndName3) throws IOException {
        /*
         * Constructor in order to keep this method reusable and clean. Needs
         * three Strings. The paths and Filenames of all three images. Image 1
         * and 2 should exist already, Image 3 will be created if all
         * requirements are met. Constructor creates the first two buffered
         * images, sets all needed variables and starts the checkAndCompare()
         * method
         */

        File file = new File(filePathAndName1);
        this.image1 = ImageIO.read(file);

        file = new File(filePathAndName2);
        this.image2 = ImageIO.read(file);

        this.pathImage3 = filePathAndName3;
        checkAndCompare();
    }

    private void checkAndCompare() throws IOException {
        /*
         * This function creates the Color blue, compares the sizes of both
         * pictures and if they are the same, creates a third image. Then it
         * loops through the two images and compares each pixel. If the pixels
         * are the same, the third image gets a blue pixel at that point
         */

        Color blue = Color.blue;

        if (image1.getHeight() == image2.getHeight()
                && image1.getWidth() == image2.getWidth()) {

            image3 = new BufferedImage(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(),
                    image1.getType());
            for (int y = 0; y < image1.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < image1.getWidth(); x++) {

                    int colorImage1 = image1.getRGB(x, y);
                    int colorImage2 = image2.getRGB(x, y);

                    if (colorImage1 == colorImage2) {

                        image3.setRGB(x, y, blue.getRGB());

                    } else {

                        // Whatever Color you want. By default it is black.

                    }

                }
            }
            savePicture3();
            System.out.println("Message: Image comparison is done");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Error: Image dimensions do not match");

        }

    }

    private void savePicture3() throws IOException {
        /*
         * This method saves the created Image into a file onto your computer.
         * The if() statement is used to check if the file was successfully
         * created, in order to avoid unwanted errors. Keep in mind, that you
         * have to change the "bmp" in ImageIO.write() to whatever format you
         * actually want
         */

        File file = new File(pathImage3);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            ImageIO.write(image3, "bmp", file);
        }
    }

}

package stackexchange;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            PictureOverlayTest test = new PictureOverlayTest(
                    "H:\\stackexchange\\file1.bmp",
                    "H:\\stackexchange\\file2.bmp",
                    "H:\\stackexchange\\file3.bmp");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYdeO.png
```

Comment: It works for me. In fact, this is a very elegant and well-written class, it works perfectly. What errors do you get?

Comment: Your issue may be that the `PictureOverlayTest` code needs to go into a different java class file named `PictureOverlayTest`, and the `Main` portion of the code needs to go into a class file named `Main`, and both files need to be within a package named `stackexchange`. If this is not the case then you will need to refacter the code to target the correct package and have the class name.

Comment: @davidalayachew, the code doesnt compile at all, it just says syntax error. As stated i am still a beginner and i know its propably a small thing that should be changed but i just cant figure it out.

Comment: These are the code errors am getting: https://postimg.cc/gallery/fJZW2k5

Comment: @RabeeTaha I see. I agree with sorifiend - I would first try and separate the 2 java classes out into 2 separate files instead of one big one - good names might be "PictureOverlayTest" and "Main". Then do ctrl+f on this character ---> ' <--- it causes your code to fail because that single quote is in a place it doesn't belong, so find it, then delete it. Let's see if that helps.